# Meaning of「時」の意識 in this sentence

Tags: meaning, translation, nuances

What does「時」の意識 mean in the following sentence?

「時間が止まってほしいと思う瞬間はどんなときですか」ーある時計の会社が、二十歳の男性と女性516人に、**「時」の意識**についてアンケート調査をしました。 ?

I got the meaning as a whole but i don't get what 意識 means in the sentence (though i know it means "counsciousness, awareness, counscious,aware, sense"). Some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've suggested,  the literal translation of "意識" would be consciousness, awareness, sense, etc... However, in general conversation/writings, we tend to use the word ”意識” when we need to explain how our mind works (what we have in our mind to the object, how we feel for the things, etc..)  For example, "政治に対する意識" means how we are facing up to the politics. In this case, the word "意識" includes the meanings of recognition/perception, understanding, realization, intention etc..

*ja.wikipedia seems to have a good explanation on this issue.
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%84%8F%E8%AD%98

So if I translate "「時」の意識" to English, it would likely be "what/how we take Time as".